# POST model binding isn't working with Namespace Routing Convention with .net core c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've been trying to use Namespace routing to build some APIs dynamically without the need to worry about hardcoding the routes. However, I did find an example from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-application-model-to-customize-attribute-routes) to use namespaces and folder structure as your API structure. Here's the sample that I have to use Namespace routing:

```
public class NamespaceRoutingConvention : Attribute, IControllerModelConvention
{
    private readonly string _baseNamespace;

    public NamespaceRoutingConvention(string baseNamespace)
    {
        _baseNamespace = baseNamespace;
    }

    public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
    {
        var hasRouteAttributes = controller.Selectors.Any(selector => selector.AttributeRouteModel != null);
        if (hasRouteAttributes)
        {
            return;
        }

        var namespc = controller.ControllerType.Namespace;
        if (namespc == null) return;
        
        var templateParts = new StringBuilder();
        templateParts.Append(namespc, _baseNamespace.Length + 1, namespc.Length - _baseNamespace.Length - 1);
        templateParts.Replace('.', '/');
        templateParts.Append("/[controller]/[action]/{environment}/{version}");
        var template = templateParts.ToString();

        foreach (var selector in controller.Selectors)
        {
            selector.AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel()
            {
                Template = template
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the controller:

```
namespace Backend.Controllers.Api.Project.Core
{
    public class UserController : ApiBaseController
    {
        public UserController()
        {
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login(LoginInput loginInput) // <-- loginInput properties return null
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest();
            
            return Ok(user);
        }
    }
}
```

in `Startup.cs`

```
namespace Backend
{
    public class Startup
    {
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
          // Let's use namespaces as the routing default way for our APIs
          services.AddControllers(options =>
          {
            options.Conventions.Add(new NamespaceRoutingConvention(typeof(Startup).Namespace + ".Controllers"));
          });
       }
    }
}
```

Everything works ok except that when I trigger a `POST` api call to `Login` action the `LoginInput` doesn't get populated the values I'm sending through `Postman` i.e. `{"username": "value", "password": "sample"}` and it always returns `null` value. I'm not sure what am I doing wrong with the `NamespaceRoutingConvention`. Bear in mind if I remove it and hard-code the route in the controller like:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/project/core/[controller]/[action]/proda/v1")]
```

It works as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - that worked as expected. Thanks man. Add your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Not sure why it has that weird behaviour though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this instead:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginInput loginInput)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest();
    
    return Ok(user);
}
```

I think that by setting `AttributeRouteModel`, you're preventing the middleware invoked by having `ApiControllerAttribute` in the Controller to do its job, and so the defaults of treating object parameters as body is not applied.
This is a guess though, I haven't been able to find the corresponding code in the source code.